# Read a growing mmap file in Go

Tags: go, system-calls, mmap

I want to read a mmap file in golang.

Another process is writing things into it so its size is growing while reading.

I am using

```
syscall.Mmap(fd int, offset int64, length int, prot int, flags int)
```

which will return a byte array.

Do I need to keep doing `syscall.Mmap` to read the updated mmap? Any better way?

Comment: Another process is writing into the virtual memory of your process? That's not normally possible. I think you are misunderstanding what the `mmap` syscall does.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: `MAP_SHARED` allows sharing between processes. From the `mmap` man page: `Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes mapping the same region`

Comment: @JimB oh, that's my bad, didn't know about `MAP_SHARED`, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

`syscall.Mmap()` is just a thin wrapper over C `mmap(2)` so it will behave the same. The memory region you get back can be updated by other processes if you've used the `syscall.MAP_SHARED` flag (and the other process did too). You don't have to do anything else except remember to call `syscall.Munmap()` when you're finished. It's probably a good candidate for `defer`ing, depending on what you're doing.

But, if someone is writing to the shared space and growing it beyond the region you mapped, then you'll have to map it again. It doesn't resize itself automatically.